# Need Some Help: Python String and Variable

Tags: python

So i am currently using python to create an AI bot, and what i want is for the user to input something like "Hi my name is Bryan" and then i want to set that last word of the input ("Bryan") as a variable for later use. But at the same time i want the code to recognise that they are saying their name, and i have got a bit of that so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is my code for this section

```
if "My name is" or "my name is" in inp:
    name =
    print("Hello", name)
```

("inp" is input btw)

Comment: `if 'My name is' or 'my name is' in inp` is not doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: You could just use `if 'my name is' in inp.lower()`:

Comment: Just lowercase and do a single comparison.

Comment: I really don't think that this is the best way to learn Python. Ads are springing up all over Facebook for chatbots, but you need some grounding in how the logic works first.

Comment: Run bool("My name is") and you'll see that it has a predefined truth value - then you can think about why

Answer (score 0):

```
if "My name is" in inp or "my name is" in inp:
#or better, if "my name is" in lower(inp):
    name = inp.split(' ')[-1]
    #or, name = inp[11:] since "my name is " is 11 characters
    print("Hello", name)
```

Comment: As well much aprreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let's say you have managed to extract the name and it's **Bryan**. How to make it a variable:

```
name = 'Bryan'      # Let's say the name is Bryan
statement = name + ' = "user"'  # returns 'Bryan = "user"'
exec(statement)     # Runs the statement as if it was code
```

And now `Bryan == 'user'`. (or any other value you wish to give it...)

As @skrx comments below, this solution allows the user to
enter malicious code. And maybe you should think about if
you really need it: You will have to use exec() every time
you want to access the variable Bryan. And to do that you
will have to store the value of the name variable somewhere
as well. Why not just store it in a dict, which allows for
easier processing, e.g.

```
user_dict[name] = 'user'  # {'Bryan': 'user'}
```

or do I misunderstand what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks been trying to work this out for ages, much aprreciated

Comment: This is a bad answer. The users will be able to enter malicious code.

Comment: @skrx: As you say, it can be dangerous. I expanded on my answer. What do you think?